# Artisan error after upgrading Laravel from 5.4 to 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have successfully updated my Laravel project from `5.4.*` to `5.7.*` however when I run the artisan command `api:route` it come returns this error:

> In RouteListCommand.php line 71:
>                                                                                    count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements
>   Countable

I have deleted the vendor folder and ran `composer update`.

**composer.json**

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.11.2",
    "bugsnag/bugsnag-laravel": "^2.0",
    "dingo/api": "1.0.*@dev",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.6",
    "dompdf/dompdf": "^0.8.2
    "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
    "laravel/socialite": "^3.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "pragmarx/google2fa-laravel": "^0.2.0",
    "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^3.0",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*"
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-fractal": "^1.0",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~8.0",
    "wpb/string-blade-compiler": "dev-laravel-5.7"
},
"require-dev": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.2",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "7.0"
},
```

Comment: What is your `PHP` version? Please check laravel5.7 server requirements here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7

Comment: php version is 7.1.3

Comment: Did you follow the upgrade guide from 5.4 -> 5.5 -> 5.6 -> 5.7? Because you'll need to go through it step by step. You can find it located on the Laravel documentation [5.4 to 5.5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade#upgrade-5.5.0), [5.5 to 5.6](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade#upgrade-5.6.0) and [5.6 to 5.7](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/upgrade#upgrade-5.7.0)

Comment: Also I've just noticed `api:route` isn't a standard command, could you post the code you have located in usually *App\Console\Commands* I think.

Comment: no sir i direct switch from 5.4 to 5.7 do i need to 5.4 -> 5.5 -> 5.6 -> 5.7 ?

Comment: You should always upgrade incrementally. There are steps along the way that you will miss if you jump directly to 5.7 from 5.4 and special notes about each upgrade that will get lost if you skip over some versions.

Comment: The upgrade guides explicitely have names like _Upgrading To 5.7.0 From 5.6_. Not sure how this allows for different interpretations...

Comment: Thanks All for suggestions  and i tried and will post result soon